# NSJSONSerialization in my function returns an error

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a function that looks like this:

```
-(void)writeArrayOnFile {

   NSArray* converterArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self swContainer]];

    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.json"];
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:converterArray options:0 error:&e];

    if (jsonData) {
        [jsonData writeToFile:url.path atomically:YES];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);

}
```

On breakpoint, the converterArray comes in with correct objects:

**[0]   Movie * 0x8d5e100   0x08d5e100**
  NSObject  NSObject
_swBtnValue BOOL    YES

_thSmallLink    UIImage *   0x8fdcd80   0x08fdcd80

_thLargeLink    __NSCFString *  @"http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/17/45/11174563_ori.jpg" 0x08fb9530

_mvName __NSCFString *  @"Delivery Man" 0x08fc48e0

_dvdReleaseDate __NSCFString *  @"2014-03-25"   0x08fb49a0

_mvRating   __NSCFString *  @"PG-13"    0x08fc4920

_mvSyn  __NSCFString *  @"From DreamWorks Pictures comes "Delivery Man", the story of affable underachiever David Wozniak, whose mundane life is turned upside down when he finds out that he fathered 533 children through sperm donations he made twenty years earlier. In debt to the mob, rejected by his pregnant girlfriend, things couldn't look worse for David when he is hit with a lawsuit from 142 of the 533 twenty-somethings who want to know the identity of the donor. As David struggles to decide whether or not he should reveal his true identity, he embarks on a journey that leads him to discover not only his true self but the father he could become as well. (c) Disney"   0x08fadd00

**[1]   Movie * 0x8fda800   0x08fda800**

**[2]   Movie * 0x8d68720   0x08d68720**

but on breakpoint the "writeToFile" method (from the jsonData object) returns this: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Movie)**

Is it because of the UIImage value? What am I not seeing? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the `UIImage`. `NSJSONSerialization` only works with `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSNull`. See the `NSJSONSerialization` docs for full details.

If you want to include the image, you'll have to convert it to `NSData` first, probably using either `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.